# Exception handling in java application

Tags: java, exception

I am going implement exception handling in my application. what care I should take. Please point out.

**My strategy:** 
I am creating my user defined Exception class. Should it extend RuntimeException or Exception?

Then I want to throw my exception from each catch block and then I would decide in my class what is the instance of of that exception type. On basis I will declare its type of seriousness like fatal critical.

difference between these both:

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException{

}

public class MyException extends Exception{

}
```

Comment: *Then i want to throw my exception from each catch block*: why would you do that? Seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: @JBNizet I have answered but am deleting as I would like to know that too.

Comment: The only legitimate reason I can think of is to decouple 3rd party Exception dependencies. For instance, you are writing application A, which depends on Adapter B, which depends on 3rd party frameworks C, D and E.

Application A should decoupled from frameworks C, D and E, so that they can be used interchangeably. For instance a method "getResource()" could throw a (checked) ResourceNotFoundException, in B which is translated from an SQLException in C, a FileNotFoundException in D, and a 404 returncode from a webservice in E.

Answer (score 2):

Please read about [checked and unchecked Exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Exceptions extending `RuntimeException` no not need a `catch` block. Exceptions extending `Exception` need a `catch` block so I think you want to extend `Exception` and use checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between these two statements.

When you do  `MyException extends RuntimeException`, then it's *unchecked* exception, so you don't have to declare your method to `throw` an *exception*.

The other statement is a *checked* exception, you have to declare the method that use it to `throw` the exception.

> Then i want to throw my exception from each catch block

Is there a reason to do that? It doesn't make sense for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first distinction that you need to make is if you want it like the checked vs unchecked exception in Java. If you do look at how an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception is and how say an SQL Exception is. 
Runtime exceptions are generally the ones which are errors or defects which occur due to an exceptional condition.

In your case, i think you dont need it to be a Runtime exception because you are going to handle it in your code.